# onblur working unexpectedly before I even select the input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onblur

I have a select tag element for which I want to add a red box shadow `onblur` after validating the user input. For some reason the `onblur()` is being called if I click anywhere in the browser where its actually supposed to work after I select the element and later takes off the focus.
This is my select element:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="income">
        <option value="-1" class="select-option">
          Gross Annual Income
        </option>
        <option>100000</option>
        <option>200000</option>
        <option>300000</option>
        <option>500000</option>
      </select>
      <span class="error incomeError"></span>
    </div>
```

this is my validation

```
  function validateIncome(income) {
    if (income === '-1') {
      $('.incomeError').text('cant be empty');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.incomeError').text('');
      return true;
    }
  }
```

My validate function is returning the right value. I'm only having trouble with the `onblur` which looks like:

```
   let userIncome = $('#income');
    userIncome.on('blur', function () {
      let userVal = $(this).val();
      if (!validateIncome(userVal)) {
        $(this).css({
          'box-shadow': '0px 0px 6px red',
        });
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          'box-shadow': '0px 0px 6px green',
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why not use the `change` event instead?

Comment: yeah it worked .. but onblur had been working for every other input and select tags of mine in the same form . In my case i want to provide a fast feedback . onchange will work only if i change the value . where i want to give a feedback even if the user donot change the value and simply just focus and unfocus the elements without selecting an option as well

Comment: Write code that reproduces the issue and post it here. Don't post all your code. write a couple of lines *from scratch* that behave like you describe. (see [mcve]).

Comment: i tried to keep it minimal as possible from my side .